# Masonry - auto adjusting when the height of an item changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, height, jquery-masonry

I am using masonry in my application. Everything worked fine except when the height of the items change (like an accordion) masonry is not adjusting the layout. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Could you show some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide more code from your app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever the items are resized, you need to tell masonary to re-layout everything:

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
    $('#container').masonry();
});
```

Comment: thanks, i just added $('#container').masonry() to the onclick event of the accordion's hide/unhide button and it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
$grid.on( 'shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse' , function() {
    $grid.masonry();
});
```